# Unable to use the Context Menu in Windows XP SP3's start menu

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu, start-menu

After a few months of use (since the last reinstall of Windows XP) my parents' computer's start menu has become typically disordered. The obvious solution to this is to right-click and then 'sort by name.'

Unfortunately, when trying this, the context-menu flashes up and then disappears (so fast as for the flash to be barely noticeable). I'm assuming that, somewhere along the line, a right-click handler's become screwed up somehow, but for the life of me I can't think how. I've used a few online virus scans ([Trend Micro's HouseCall](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/uk/), [Bitdefender](http://www.bitdefender.co.uk/scanner/online/free.html) and [Panda Security's 'ActiveScan'](http://www.pandasecurity.com/homeusers/solutions/activescan/)), along with AVG installed to their machine to try and rule out malicious software (all scans coming up negative).

Are there any obvious culprits I should look at? Or registry settings that can be removed/amended/deleted to enable right-click to work as normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebooting normally takes care of this problem.

If not, try : Start, Control Panel, Taskbar and Start Menu, Start Menu, Customize, check `Enable dragging and dropping`, OK, OK.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a context menu hook thats gone missing, try disabling the entries you don't use with the free utility http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html it will probably fix your issue.
If you get confused try only disabling entries from unknown sources, (office's, and windows media player stay)